# Desktop entry for dockerized applications

Tags: docker, docker-compose, desktop-application

I know that we can package desktop applications inside docker containers [This repo of jessfrazilla includes many dockerized desktop applications](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles). But can we create Desktop entries of those applications as shown below.

[image].

Creating desktop entries means i can start/stop application from Unity dash instead of `docker start <container-name>`.`docker-compose` could be the way but i do not know how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://msftstack.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/adding-a-docker-container-icon-in-ubuntu-unity-desktop/

Comment: I am looking for a general solution for all DE's of linux.